# Attempted to jump my car, it turns over and starts but then shuts off?

Tags: battery, civic

I was unable to drive so my 2006 Honda Civic sat idle for a little less than 3 months. We attempted to jump start it and while the cables were connected the dash lights came on, the headlights would turn on and it would function, however when I attempted to start it it would start then immediately shut off. It had no mechanical problems prior to this and I’m not sure where to go from here

Comment: Try this, Insert your key into ignition and turn it to the ON position. (do not crank). Now look at your instrument cluster to see if you see a green flashing key, If you do then your key has lost programming which is common for Honda's left sitting with flat batteries and you will need to have it reprogrammed. If you see the green key light up and then go out then its ok and you have other problems.

Comment: I would suggest to have your battery checked. If it's good it needs to be fully charged. If it's bad you need to put in a good fully charged battery. Then the charging system can be checked. The battery cables sould be cleaned at both ends. This is the first step to find out what is wrong. Almost all other problems can not be found without doing this first. And maybe you will not need to go any further because this may fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with narkelpt; if it is not security then fuel delivery would be the next step.Do you have more then one key, sometimes a key will go bad and the second will still work. Welcome to Stack.